# C++ catch base exception, throw child

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following exceptions.

```
class BaseException  : public Exception     {};
class ChildException : public BaseException {};
class FooException   : public BaseException {};

int throw_it() {
  try {
    throw ChildException();
  } catch(BaseException& exc) {
    throw exc;
  }
}
```

Is there any way for me to have the `catch` clause in `throw_it()` throw a `ChildException` even though I'm catching `BaseException`?

Assume for the purposes of this question, that `throw_it()` may throw either a `ChildException` or a `FooException` and I don't know which one at compile time.

**EDIT**

This may be a more complete example of my problem.

```
class BaseException : public Exception {};
class AException    : public Exception {};
class BException    : public Exception {};
class CException    : public Exception {};
class DException    : public Exception {};
class EException    : public Exception {};
class FException    : public Exception {};
class GException    : public Exception {};

void throw_it() {
  try {
    // Code
  } catch(AException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  } catch(BException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  } catch(CException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  } catch(DException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  } catch(EException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  } catch(FException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  } catch(GException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  }
}
```

I am trying to write it like this:

```
void throw_it() {
  try {
    // Code
  } catch(BaseException exc) {
    log(exc);
    throw(exc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: @nawaz This is example code.

Comment: `FooException` derives from itself?!

Comment: @KerrekSB Should have been `BaseException` edited.

Comment: @screenmutt: So you want to rethrow all exceptions, not just some specific ones? (I'm asking this question, after seeing your edit).

Comment: @Nawaz all exceptions should be rethrown.

Comment: @screenmutt: then I don't see any problem. All you've to do is : Catch the exception by reference and throw it as I've explained in any answer. Write `throw;`, not `throw e;`. You don't have to do anything else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is one way to do that. But I think that would be a bad idea.

The real question is, why would you want to do that?

If you want to rethrow the exception irrespective of its type, then simply rethrow it as:

```
catch(BaseException const & e)
{
     log(e);
     throw; //it rethrows the exception irrespective of its type!
}
```

That should work. The magic happens in `throw` — since the exception is caught by *reference*, it will throw the exception of the derived types, means if the exception is `ChildException`, then `throw` will throw `ChildException`, not `BaseException`, even though the catch mentions `BaseException`.

---

If you want to rethrow a *specific* exception (as opposed to all), then *first* catch it by  specific type:

```
//first write a lambda to avoid duplication of code!
auto handle_exception = [&](BaseException const & e) 
{
    //your duplicate code
};

try { /*....*/ }
catch(ChildException const & e)  //catch it by specific type
{
     handle_exception(e); //invoke the lambda to handle exception!
     //any additional (non-duplicate) code can go here or above it!

     throw; //it rethrows the exception!
}
catch(BaseException const & e) //the more general case
{
     handle_exception(e); //invoke the lambda to handle the exception
     //any additional (non-duplicate) code can go here or above it!
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There are almost 10 different exceptions all inheriting from the same base type which need to run three identical lines of code. That's 40 lines needed when it should be 4 and a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: @screenmutt: There are functions and lambdas to cope with duplicate code. Please use them.

Comment: Do you have an example of what this would look like? While the lines of code are identical, they call different functions based upon the exception type (overloaded methods).

Comment: That's what virtual functions are for.

Comment: @Nawaz That is better, but still a lot of duplicate code. Isn't there some way to catch them all, cast to a specific subclass and then rethrow it?

Comment: @screenmutt: I don't see *"a lot of duplicate code"* in my answer. Casting would be more ugly (and possibly dangerous too) than this.

Comment: Imagine 10 exceptions being caught in 10 different functions. All of them doing the exact same thing, calling `duplicate_code(e)` and `throw`. That's a lot of repetition!

Comment: @screenmutt: If you don't do that, you're STILL going to write lots of casting **and** checking, then rethrow. However, if you want to throw all exceptions irrespective of types, then `throw;` is all you need.

Comment: But vs. 100's of lines? It makes more sense to have it in a single spot.

Comment: @screenmutt: How exactly? Do you have any count how many casting you're going to use? And how many places?

Comment: There are around 10 functions, which are part of an API. Each of them can throw a number of exceptions inherited from the base class. All of them log the exception before throwing it.

Comment: ... also note that in this approach, mutiple use of `catch` is equivalent to casting, but it is *safe* casting, as it is done by the compiler itself.

Comment: @screenmutt: So you think you want to write it in one function, and all other `9` functions will work without doing anything in them? Is that so? The point is, whatever you do, casting or catch, you've to do in all the 10 functions.

Comment: But I could catch the base in all 10 and hand it off to a single function to log.

Comment: @screenmutt: Then use cast in *that single* function. BTW, your question was not clear enough to that point.

Comment: @screenmutt: I would suggest you to edit your question and write code that does the job but with lots of code duplication. Once that part is clear in the question, then asks how to *avoid* the duplicate code. In that case, it would be clear to use what you want to do, and what you want to avoid.

Comment: @Nawaz Is there any way to pass the exception to the log function by it's specific type?

Comment: @screenmutt: Only if you use cast, but that would be an ugly solution. A more elegant solution would be to use virtual function, then you don't have to worry about the specific type, in the `log` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(BaseException& exc) {
  throw; // thows excact expeption
}
```

search for "throw;" on page http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/